# Access Django custom user profile field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I added a custom user profile field `role` with the following `models.py`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (792, 'Student'),
        (172, 'Teacher'),
        (864, 'Supervisor'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

What is the best way to return the int value assigned to the `role`? For example if the current logged in user is assigned the role of `"Teacher"`, I want to be able to use the `172` value elsewhere like in `views.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently logged in user is `request.user`, so

```
request.user.profile.role
```

will return `172`, and

```
request.user.profile.get_role_display()
```

will return `"Teacher"`. Note that you should omit parentheses if you are using the latter in a template.